# App doesn't render when pushing to production NextJS/React/Vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have a problem not being able to make my app work when I'm pushing to production.

I'll leave some screenshots and a bunch of code, hopefully someone can help me

```
<div style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
   <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={10} checkboxSelection={false} className={classes.root} />
</div>

const columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
    { field: 'denumireProdus', headerName: 'Denumire produs', width: 300 },
    { field: 'pret', headerName: 'Pret', type: 'number', width: 120 },
    {
      field: 'cantitate',
      headerName: 'Cantitate',
      type: 'number',
      width: 120,
    },
    {
      field: 'discount',
      headerName: 'Discount',
      description: 'This column has a value getter and is not sortable.',
      type: 'number',
      width: 120,
    },
  ];
  const rows = [
    { id: 1, denumireProdus: 'Bere Bucegi', pret: 25, cantitate: 35, discount : 25 },
    { id: 2, denumireProdus: 'Bere Bucegi', pret: 25, cantitate: 35, discount : 25 },
    { id: 3, denumireProdus: 'Bere Bucegi', pret: 25, cantitate: 35, discount : 25 },
    { id: 4, denumireProdus: 'Bere Bucegi', pret: 25, cantitate: 35, discount : 25 },
    { id: 5, denumireProdus: 'Bere Bucegi', pret: 25, cantitate: 35, discount : 25 },
    { id: 6, denumireProdus: 'Bere Bucegi', pret: 25, cantitate: 35, discount : 25 },
  ];
```

[image: localhost]
[image: production server]

Comment: Is the data for your `DataGrid` hardcoded like in your snippet or coming from an external source?

Comment: Which part "isn't rendering"? Are you referring to the styling - not showing all the CSS or something?